# Pandas: filtering by field contained in set

Tags: python, pandas, filter, set

I have a *DataFrame df* and a set of *user_ids: set*. How can I choose a slice of *df* containing only users in the set. Like:

```
df[df.user_id in user_ids]
```

Now working that way because:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: `df[df.user_id.isin(user_ids)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for `boolean mask` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   B  user_id
0  4        1
1  5        2
2  6        3

user_ids = set([1,2])

print (df.user_id.isin(user_ids))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: user_id, dtype: bool

df1 = df[df.user_id.isin(user_ids)]
print (df1)
   B  user_id
0  4        1
1  5        2
```

Comment: Dude.  How likely is it that this is the first `isin` question on SO? ;-)